# Dynamically set max-messages-per-poll property of pollerMetaData

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to change the max-messages-per-poll depending on a counter value. This should enable me to fetch a subset of records that are stored in MongoDbMessageStore

I tried adding AroundAdvice on the PollerMetaData. Used DirectFieldAccessor to set the maxMessagesPerPoll value. However, with each poll, the entire dataset in MongoDbMessageStore is being polled and removed.

Comment: Please add some code you wrote so it will be easier to figure out where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to show some configuration and logic you try to perform, but it looks like you have a `QueueChannel` with that `MongoDbMessageStore` as a persistence storage for messages.

The `QueueChannel` is consumed by the `PollingConsumer` which has a `setMaxMessagesPerPoll()` you can use in your logic.

So, whenever you need to change that value, you just find an appropriate bean for that endpoint and call that method to change the settings at runtime.